# Exception handling for regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r

I've found several related questions, but haven't found one that I solves my problem yet, please let me know if I'm missing a question that addresses this.

Essentially I want to use a regular expression to find a pattern but with an exception based on the preceding characters. For example, I have the following text object ("muffins") as a vector and I want to match the names ("Sarah","Muffins", and "Bob").:

```
muffins
```

> [1] "Dear Sarah,"
>   [2] "I love your dog, Muffins, who is adorable and very friendly. However, I cannot say I enjoy the \"muffins\" he regularly leaves in my front yard. Please consider putting him on a leash outside and properly walking him like everyone else in the neighborhood."
>
> [3] "Sincerely,"
>   [4] "Bob"

My approach was the search for capitalized words and then exclude words capitalized for grammatical reasons, such as the beginning of a sentence.

```
 pattern = "\\b[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b"
 m = gregexpr(pattern,muffins)
 regmatches(muffins,m)
```

This pattern gets me most of the way, returning:

> [[1]]
>   [1] "Dear"  "Sarah"
>
> [[2]]
>   [1] "Muffins" "However" "Please"
>
> [[3]]
>   [1] "Sincerely"
>
> [[4]]
>   [1] "Win"

and I can identify some of the sentence beginnings with:

```
 pattern2 = "[.]\\s[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b"
 m = gregexpr(pattern2,muffins)
 regmatches(muffins,m)
```

but I can't seem to do both simultaneously, where I say I want pattern where pattern2 is not the case.

I've tried several combinations that I thought would work, but with little success. A few of the ones I tried:

```
pattern2 = "(?<![.]\\s[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b)(\\b[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b)"
pattern2 = "(^[.]\\s[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b)(\\b[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b)"
```

Any advice or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: did you have these `[4]`,`[3]` numberings in your input?

Comment: @AvinashRaj those are the vector numbers in R when returning the object muffins. They are not part of the text. Thanks for asking, next time I'll try to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You maybe looking for a negative look-behind.

```
pattern = "(?<!\\.\\s)\\b[[:upper:]]\\w+\\b"
m = gregexpr(pattern,muffins, perl=TRUE)
regmatches(muffins,m)

# [[1]]
# [1] "Dear"  "Sarah"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "Muffins"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "Sincerely"
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] "Bob"
```

The look behind part `(?<!\\.\\s)` makes sure there's not a period and a space immediately before the match.

Comment: i think he don't want to match Dear and Sincerely.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I focused on just answering the question about combining the two different regular expressions. I agree that "Dear" and "Sincerely" don't belong as a match, but they don't violate any of the rules that the OP gave. They are indistinguishable from "Bob" in this text.

Comment: You are missing a `perl=TRUE` on the `gregexpr` call.

Comment: @thelatemail In my test, I didn't need it (R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)). Did it not work for you?

Comment: I don't know about r. Does the numbers and `"` exists in the input?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, it does not. `muffins` is a vector with 4 character elements. R prints each of those elements to the console with quotes and `[]`-style indexes.

Comment: does my answer would help the op? If no, let me know, i'll delete it.

Comment: @MrFlick - same version here on Win7. Fails with '*invalid regular expression*' but then works with `perl=TRUE`.

Comment: @thelatemail I am on a Mac. I put it in just to be safe. Thanks.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think your regex works perfectly for this sample.  If you think it would work well for all similar input, then it's a fine answer. I think there are just going to be many edge cases where it would be impossible to only identify names.

Comment: @MrFlick, thanks this is exactly what I was looking for - I did not know it was called a "negative look behind." I am just starting to teach myself regular expressions, so this is very helpful for generally as well. Yes, eventually I'll exclude "Dear" and "Sincerely" as well, but I am trying to build bigger expressions piece by piece. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would match only the names `Bob`, `Sarah` and `Muffins`,

```
(?<=^)[A-Z][a-z]+(?=$)|(?<!\. )[A-Z][a-z]+(?=,[^\n])|(?<= )[A-Z][a-z]+(?=,$)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/25)

Comment: This is super helpful, and I had not seen the regex tester, which I'll be sure to make extensive use of. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Trying to use regular expressions to identify names becomes a problem. There is no hope of working reliably. It is very complicated to match names from arbitrary data. If extracting these names is your goal, you need to approach this in a different way instead of simply trying to match an uppercase letter followed by word characters.

Considering your vector is as you posted in your question:

```
x <- c('Dear Sarah,', 
       'I love your dog, Muffins, who is adorable and very friendly. However, I cannot say I enjoy the "muffins" he regularly leaves in my front yard. Please consider putting him on a leash outside and properly walking him like everyone else in the neighborhood.', 
       'Sincerely', 
       'Bob')

m = regmatches(x, gregexpr('(?<!\\. )[A-Z][a-z]{1,7}\\b(?! [A-Z])', x, perl=T))
Filter(length, m)

# [[1]]
# [1] "Sarah"

# [[2]]
# [1] "Muffins"

# [[3]]
# [1] "Bob"
```

Comment: Yeah, as I went along with the example I learned that extracting names reliably is probably impossible. That said I'm really just generating examples and problems to teach myself. Thanks for answer!